# A Question About Blender's Baking Angle

Tags: texture-baking

i am texturing my mesh and i want to see how it looks with light and shadow on it before i bake it. i am looking at it right from front(Orthographic-1)(picture1) and then i look at it again from another angle(pic2). They look totally different. i just wonder from what angle Blender bakes textures ? How to understand rendered and baked results match eachother ?

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]